# How would I read a folder of images on my computer into a dataframe on Jupyter Notebooks?

Tags: python

This is my code right now, I have used a for loop to go through all the images in the folder and use the PIL library to read it into an array.

```
import cv2
import os

folder = '/Users/x/x/x/x'

def load_images_from_folder(folder):
    images = []
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder,filename))
        if img is not None:
            images.append(img)
    return images
    img = Image.fromarray(images_array,'RGB', dtype = object)
```

Comment: you don't really want to read images into a dataframe, numpy arrays are much better suited here

Comment: I need the image for a project im working on

Comment: I'm sure you do, but I'm suggesting you leave it as an array rather than trying to shoehorn it into a dataframe